# Photoshop: how can I see both the mask and the masked contents?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

When I have a photo with a mask in Photoshop, I want to be able to edit this mask with a brush, e.g. I want to remove the sky from the photo. But as far as I know, I can only view the mask *or* the photo, but not both. I would like to be able to view them both, so that the mask is an "overlay" of the photo. How can I do that?

I hope that was clear...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mean like 'quick mask'?  Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on your layer mask.  Your mask will be highlighted in red, with your photo still showing.

Answer (score 9):

You can view the mask of a layer overlaid on top of the canvas by pressing <kbd>\</kbd> (backslash, usually the key above return). This toggles it on and off for the currently selected layer. You can also open the channels panel and toggle it from there.

[image: Channel Mask]

Be careful though. The small box around the layer contents and mask indicates which one you're painting on.

Here's what it looks like when you're painting on the layer itself.

[image: Paint on layer]

And when you're painting on the mask.

[image: Paint on mask]

You can change the overlay colour by double clicking the quick mask button in the tool panel (second from the bottom).

[image: Quick Mask Options]

Or by right clicking on the mask in the layers panel and choosing Mask Options.

Photoshop CS6 shown, but this stuff hasn't changed for a while. Should be almost identical in all recent versions.

Comment: When the mask layer is visible (with `/`) you can also hide the RGB layer (and only show the mask layer) with `\``.

Comment: Is ` \\` doing the same thing (just to the current layer) as `alt`+`shift`+`click on mask`? Or are those technically different viewing modes? If so, what's the difference?